# After converting a data frame to csv file in colab,I cannot save the file to my google drive

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Files /Copy of weather_data.xlsx')
k2 = df.head(4)
k2.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Files/new_fileee.csv',index=False)
```

This generates an error saying there is no such file or directory

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, everyone puts the error code in the message, rather than a picture. Have you viewed these sites - **Pandas Dataframe to CSV File – Export Using .to_csv()** https://datagy.io/pandas-dataframe-to-csv/; **pandas.read_excel** -https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Looking at your error, I'm presuming you've tested your output...

```
print(k2)
```

Maybe try to get the path using the os.path.dirname

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_excel("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Files/Copy of the weather.xlsx")
k2 = df.head()
dirname = os.path.dirname("content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Files/Copy of the weather.xlsx")
newfilename = "new_fileee.csv"
csvfile = dirname + "/" + newfilename
k2.to_csv(csvfile, index = false)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time.Unfortunately, this is not working the same error returns saying that there is no such file or directory.

Comment: test your current file path -- `split = os.path.split("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Files/Copy of the weather.xlsx")    print(split).   print(split[0]).    print(split[1])`.   Do you get an output?

Comment: ('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Files', 'Copy of the weather.xlsx')
/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Files
Copy of the weather.xlsx  **This is the output**

Comment: if you add the split line into your code, the update `dirname = os.path.dirname("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Files/Copy of the weather.xlsx")` to be `dirname = split[0]` What happens?